# Need help for IBatis?

Tags: ibatis.net

I am using IBatis for my applicaiton. I am using IBatis 1.6.1 version.I thought it can handle all operations related to DB connections. But I am having little bit concern about this now. Sometimes I am getting the following error details to my log file,

Message
Unable to open connection to "MySQL, MySQL provider 5.0.8.1".
Source
IBatisNet.DataMapper
Stack
at IBatisNet.DataMapper.SqlMapSession.OpenConnection(String connectionString) at IBatisNet.DataMapper.SqlMapSession.OpenConnection() at IBatisNet.DataMapper.Commands.DbCommandDecorator.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader() at IBatisNet.DataMapper.MappedStatements.MappedStatement.RunQueryForObject(RequestScope request, ISqlMapSession session, Object parameterObject, Object resultObject) at IBatisNet.DataMapper.MappedStatements.MappedStatement.ExecuteQueryForObject(ISqlMapSession session, Object parameterObject, Object resultObject) at IBatisNet.DataMapper.MappedStatements.MappedStatement.ExecuteQueryForObject(ISqlMapSession session, Object parameterObject) at IBatisNet.DataMapper.SqlMapper.QueryForObject(String statementName, Object parameterObject) at Sunya.VideoStreaming.Persistence.SchoolRepository.GetSchoolDetailsByUrl(String SchoolUrl) in D:\SVN\Sprint104\Persistence\SchoolRepository.cs:line 192 at EduVisionBasePage.GetSchoolUrl(School& _school) at ASP.global_asax.Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e) at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
Message
Too many connections
Source
MySql.Data
Stack
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.OpenPacket() at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Authenticate411() at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Authenticate() at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open() at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetPooledConnection() at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetConnection() at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open() at IBatisNet.DataMapper.SqlMapSession.OpenConnection(String connectionString)

Does someone has some idea about the error?

Answer (score 0):

[iBATIS](http://ibatis.apache.org/) has been around for quite a while (2001), and I have my doubts that there's a major bug in the MySQL provider. You mentioned that the error occurs "sometimes" - if it's intermittent, perhaps the problem lies elsewhere. "Unable to open connection" is likely to mean just that. Network errors, database outages, too many unreleased connections, authentication issues, etc. might all cause this error.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the JDBC transaction manager set the datasource to 'UNPOOLED' in you myBatisConfig.xml

`<transactionManager type="JDBC"/>
    <dataSource type="UNPOOLED">
.
.
.
    </dataSource>
</environment>`

That is the short answer.  My hunch is The connection pool class is holding connections too long.   Lowering the values for 'poolMaximunActiveConnection' and 'poolMaximunIdleConnections' may solve the problem.

Notes: using myBatis 3.0.3 Java,  mySql Windows 5.5.9

search terms:  iBatis, myBatis, 'Too many connections', mySQL